# log4net with .NET 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, log4net

I've thrown together some code to tinker with the new .Net 4.0/VS 2010 pieces, but I can't seem to find a build of my logging framework of choice (log4net) for 4.0, and I'm getting reference errors with the 2.0 version.  Is there a 4.0 version available somewhere?  I'm not asking for new features, just a version that's already been rebuilt against the new assemblies.  Anyone know where I can find a build of 1.2.10 built for the 4.0 framework?

Comment: I think I remember seeing in-proc side-by-side for 2.0/4.0-compat, but that doesn't appear to allow my 4.0 code to reference the 2.0 log4net library.

Comment: Have you tried taking a log4net source project and running it through VS2010's upgrade process?

Comment: I have pulled the source for 1.2.10 from the SVN server and run it through the upgrade process.  It looks like so long as I define the _NET_2_0 symbol and add attribute to get the Level1 security-enforcement rules, things work.  Obviously, there's more work involved for the complete 4.0 update, so I'm hoping someone has already started on that work.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

log4net has a known issue of referencing a System.Web component which is not part of the [.NET Framework 4 Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx) and the VS2010 by default sets project target to be the *lightweighted* Client Profile.
The solution is to change the target to .NET Framework 4:

Right click project -> properties -> Application.
Change:

```
 .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
```

to be:

```
 .NET Framework 4
```

... and that should work, i.e. you can use log4net again...

Comment: I should say the latest releases already added support for Client profile, so no need to target the full one.

Comment: Downloaded today latest release, it doesn't support ClientProfile with .NET 4.0

Comment: Just downloaded latest binaries (1.2.11) and it contains a version compatible with 4.0 Client Profile in \bin\net-cp\4.0\release. Just tested it and works like a charm !