# system.data.sqlite .net 4

Tags: .net, sqlite

Is there a .Net 4 version of System.Data.SQLite?

At the moment I get this error:

> Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.

What is the "additional configuration information" that is needed, or alternatively is there another version that I can use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/net-4-0-project-reference-2-0-assembly

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: worked after removing"<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>" and adding that.

Comment: Where the jeffin' hell do I make this change?

Comment: @Hades, in your app.config file.

Comment: Funny it's a file that I can't seem to find.

Comment: @Hades, it's not there by default, you have to add it.  Right click on the project in the solution explorer and choose Add-> New Item... then choose "Application Configuration File"

Answer (score 4):

According to the [forums of PhxSoftware](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/2040/8474.aspx#8474):

> It's not high on my priority list
>   right at the moment.  When VS2010
>   comes closer to release I'll be
>   updating the library to work with it.

Although the message was posted in october 2009 there are some [workarounds](http://www.meadow.se/wordpress/?p=393).

Further there [seems](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/2040/9056.aspx#9056) to be an updated (temporary) version specially for .NET 4:

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is now.

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

And you can use NuGet to install it as well. With nuget, its easy to choose between x86/x64/both, http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=system.data.sqlite .

Comment: Now you can use nuget to download it.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote. In fact your reply was fine. I would have liked some more information however.

Comment: Hate to break it to you after 4 years, but it is only fitting since you answered after 2 years with 'there has always been', It didn't

Comment: @Behrooz My bad, there hasn't been until [2010-11-24](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/timeline?b=2011-01-31+20:46:59&n=50), 6 months after your question, 9 months before my answer.