# Problem Upgrading NHibernate SQLite Application to .Net 4.0

Tags: .net, nhibernate, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate

I have a WPF Application using Fluent NHibernate 1.0 RTM and System.Data.SQLite 1.0.65 that works fine in .Net 3.5. When I try to upgrade it to .Net 4.0 everything compiles but I get a runtime error where the innermost exception is this:

```
`The IDbCommand and IDbConnection implementation in the assembly System.Data.SQLite could not be found.`
```

The only change made to the project was switching the Target Framework to 4.0.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605490/system-data-sqlite-net-4

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use a version of SQLite that is [compatible with .NET 4.0](http://geeklyeverafter.blogspot.com/2010/03/sqlite-available-for-net-40.html). You might also try putting this in your app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Putting that into the app.config fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If the acepted answer doesnt work for you, check if you have 64bit system, and if you do, right click on your project -> properties -> build -> set platform target to x86 and rebuild.