# Working c# soluction .net 4 with fluent NHibernate and SqLite

Tags: sqlite, .net-4.0, fluent-nhibernate

I know that there are wery similar question posted and already answered here, but those solution weren't useful for me. I want to create a project which will use sqlite database, fluent nhibernate (all in .Net 4). Problem is that I can't find working example which will act as reference for me. All my efforts ended with Exception(Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver, NHibernate, Version=3.1.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4.) on line:

new SchemaExport(configuration).Create(true, true);

I added those lines in app.config mentioned in other solutions.

So to summarize: can anybody post an exact way to create a solution with some sample code(preferably tutorial from fluent nhibernate get started guide) which will work in .net 4 ?

If you can please post files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem may be solved by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2627209/102554), quoted below for convenience.  I see you already changed app config, but **note the link to a post about getting .NET 4 compatible versions of SQLite.**

**Quote:**

You need to use a  [version of SQLite that is compatible with .NET 4.0](http://geeklyeverafter.blogspot.com/2010/03/sqlite-available-for-net-40.html). You might also try putting this in your app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

**/Quote**

Once you get your sample working, please load it to the FNH GitHub.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer. I used Nuget, so I thought that file versions where ok. Will try with this file and post results.

Comment: Everything works fine. Thanks for help! I had to uninstall previous version and used link above. Next I had to reference installed dll and all voilà :) App.config entry wasn't needed.

PS. Can you post tutorial for that FNH thing ? I will gladly post source files.