# Does anyone have an updated version of the SQLite .NET assembly, ie. SQLite 3.6.23.1 + possibly .NET 4.0 support?

Tags: .net, sqlite

I'm at my wits end with the best .NET assembly version of SQLite, the one found at http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com.

The only maintainer doesn't seem to have the time to update the library and it generally takes months, if not more, for newer versions to surface.

Luckily, he has published the source code, so I'm hoping that someone else has made his/her own copy of it, and made the changes, and would be willing to share a copy.

I've seen comments on the forums for the library to this effect, but sadly even the forum software seems to be grinding to a halt these days as password reminder emails seems to be lost to the big void, so I can't ask the few there that has said they have done it.

So I'm here, hopefully the big userbase of StackOverflow can help.

What I'm looking for:

- Updated with the latest changes to SQLite, ie. SQLite version 3.6.23.1
- Possibly built for .NET 4.0 (I can do that if I can get a copy of working source)

Does anyone have, or know of anyone, that has done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this post: [system.data.sqlite .net 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605490/system-data-sqlite-net-4/2605505#2605505)

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/2040/8474.aspx#8474

Comment: Fully aware of the workarounds, and the published installer is for .NET 4.0 RC2, I'd rather avoid having to manually hack every app.config file to ensure the file loads for the RTM runtime.

Comment: I found a *beta* version here: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/storage/29/9056/SQLite-1.0.65.1-vs2010rc-net4-setup.zip 

Tested it at home and works pretty well. But it's still a beta ofcourse.