# Quartz.NET RemoteScheduler with AdoJobStore unable to find assembly

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net

HI All,

I have successfully created a Quartz.NET remote server running inside a windows service. I followed examples 12 in the source and slightly modified it to use AdoJobStore with sqlite.

On remote client I created a windows form application and successfully connected with the server. Everything went fine until the point where I'm trying to actually add jobs.

```
        JobDetail detail = new JobDetail(job.JobName, "default", typeof(NativeJob));
        detail.Description = job.Description;            
        JobDataMap map = new JobDataMap();
        map.Put(NativeJob.PropertyCommand, job.Command);
        map.Put(NativeJob.PropertyParameters, job.Arguments);            
        detail.JobDataMap = map;

        // create trigger
        Trigger trigger = new CronTrigger(job.JobName, "default", job.CronExpression);

        //Add job w/ trigger
        _scheduler.ScheduleJob(detail, trigger);
```

The last line above failed with Exception :

Unable to find assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'.

The SQLite assembly is there. Oddly enough this doesn't happen when I'm using RamJobStore. Anybody please help.

Comment: I finally replaced SQLite with SqlServer and it works fine. No more trouble finding the assembly. If anybody had any luck using SQLite with Quartz.NET please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably running into the [SQlite x86 vs x64 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite) or the [SQlite on .NET 4 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605490/system-data-sqlite-net-4).