# Unable to insert data into database

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlite

I am using SQLite.

When I try to insert data into the tables I get the following:

> Mixed mode assembly is built against
>   version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime
>   and cannot be loaded in the 4.0
>   runtime without additional
>   configuration information.

[I am using ADO.NET 2.0 Provider for SQLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/)

Comment: Please Close this post as this a duplicate question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605490/system-data-sqlite-net-4)
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode-a)
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604663/what-does-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-do-in-the-net-4-config)

are links to previous questions that will help.

Comment: I did try searching  first, but didn't see them