# What happens in a .Net 4 app when referencing .net 2 assemblies?

Tags: .net-2.0, .net-4.0

I have an application I want to upgrade to .NET 4, but I have a couple 3rd party assemblies that reference the .NET 2 BCL.

I seem to remember reading something that says they should play nice, but I can't find any documentation on the subject. ( I think my question posed to Google is just too broad, with not enough .Net 4 material out there yet )

Can anyone help me find documentation on what will happen in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading Scott Guthrie's post, [Multi-Targeting Support (VS 2010 and .NET 4 Series)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/27/multi-targeting-support-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx),  correctly then that will work fine.

Of Interest?: [.NET 4.0 project reference 2.0 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/net-4-0-project-reference-2-0-assembly)

Comment: In fact,as far as I understood it, 2.0 dll's are automatically upgraded to 4.0 when used inside a 4.0 project. So your 2.0 dlls do not run against the 2.0 runtime, but against the 4.0 runtime. Probably they do something at the MSIL level to make this happen. I think side-by-side executions is something solely used in situations like eg. plugins written in 2.0 for outlook, where no compilation and linking happens.

Answer (score 0):

> The .NET Framework 4 works side by side with older Framework versions. Applications that are based on earlier versions of the Framework will continue to run on the version targeted by default.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=0a391abd-25c1-4fc0-919f-b21f31ab88b7

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to reference StructureMap in one of my class libraries. Orginally it was created by VS2010 to use the .NET 4 client profile. Turns out, I had to changed this to the full .NET 4 framework, otherwise structuremap would not be recognized.