# Will it be any performance issues when referencing 2.0/3.5 assemblies from .net 4.0 project?

Tags: .net, clr, .net-4.0

I've found a lot information in internet about this, but I can't answer for myself; will .net 4.0 application work slower if I add .net 3.5/2.0 assembly, and should I recompile them in 4.0 if I can?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET 4.0 project reference 2.0 assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/net-4-0-project-reference-2-0-assembly)

Comment: @Randolpho: Not even close to being a duplicate.

Comment: Don't worry about micro-optimization.  The only time you should really worry about optimizations like this is after it is written and you know it is a problem.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: You're right; I regretted that almost immediately, but I can't undo it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should worry about performance in this scenario.  The 2.0/3.5 assemblies may actually work faster, since there is potentially less code overhead (in some rare cases).

But that's all micro-optimization anyway, and the only way you're going to know for sure is to profile your code, and see how fast it really is.  I think you're going to find in the vast majority of cases that it isn't going to matter.

Comment: Yes, but dzen will be lost :)
So there is no difference between refferencing 4.0 or earlier assemblies, is there? Will two runtimes be loaded or not? (Just assemblies, not com-objects)