# Code throwing WebException works in .NET 3.5 but not in 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I am writing code to check whether a file exists or not. If the file exists it should throw a WebException. The code is below; if I run this code in .NET 3.5 it throws a WebException, but if use .NET 4.0 the exception is not thrown. I *want* the exception to be thrown so I can validate the file's existence.

```
bool IsExists = true;
try
{
    // string ftpServer = "FTP://111.111.111.111/16FebTo15Mar/Backup/MT_Backup/";
    string userName = "gff";
    // string filename = "sachin";
    string password = "gff@123";
    string ftppath= "FTP://111.111.111.111/16FebTo15Mar/Backup/MT_Backup/bh/"; 
                    // Ftpurl + new FileInfo(EmpFldr).Name + "/";

    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftppath);
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.PrintWorkingDirectory;
    // request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    IsExists = false;
}
return IsExists;
```

Comment: Not very sure but try [changing the `UsePassive` property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604693/ftp-throws-webexception-only-in-net-4-0) for the ftprequest

Comment: Is an exception still being thrown? Catch the more general exception and see what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check for the existence of a file via FTP then [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347897/how-to-check-if-file-exists-on-ftp-before-ftpwebrequest).

> I'd recommend using the following WebRequestMethod instead, this works for me on all servers I tested, even ones which would not return a file size.
>
> ```
> WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp
> ```

Comment: Also other idea is use `request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;` and parse list to find flie. Since not all FTP web request types are properly implemneted by Microsoft.