# Create Entities instance. (connection string)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, database-connection

I have a problem when trying to use Entity framework to connect to my database. I dont really know how to explain so I post some code. I want to make an instance of dbEntities and use it to connect to my DB, in the second section you can see my connection string. I get the following error when I try to run this;

> XampParseException was unhandled:
>
> The invocation of the constructor on
> type 'test.MainWindow' that matches
> the specified binding constraints
> threw an exception.' Line number '3'
> and line position '9'.

And a inner exeption...

> Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.":nul.

I get to the line public dbEntities() : base(....) but there it crashes. I hope some one could give me a hint what to do.

/Nick

```
public class LinqConnection
{

    private readonly dbEntities _linq;
    private static LinqConnection _instance;

    private LinqConnection()
    {
        _linq = new dbEntities();
    }

    public static dbEntities Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new LinqConnection();
            return _instance._linq;
        }
    }
}

public dbEntities()
        : base("metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string=';data source=db.db3;Password=testpass';", "dbEntities")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
```

Comment: This looks like it's unrelated to EF - are you using a .NET 2 assembly within a .NET 4 project? What other dependencies does your project have?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a problem with SQLite + .NET 4.0 - check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode-a). It is not related to Entity framework or connection string.