# How Can I add new app.Config file?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, .net-4.0

I'm trying to use SQLite in my .Net application but it throws an exception and I get this

> Additional information: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode-a) I read the solution that's is changing app.config file, but in my solution folder there is no configuration file, where is that configuration file? what should I change?
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What 'additional configuration' is necessary to reference a .NET 2.0 mixed mode assembly in a .NET 4.0 project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode-a)

Comment: @Rune FS, yes I read that one as well, I have the same problem, my problem is about the file that I'm supposed to modify, I don't which it is and I can't find it.

Comment: in the case of the question "How can I get an app.config file" the answer would be: Right click you're project, choose Add>new item... and then choose "application configuration file"
If that's your question I suggest rephrasing this question to make that clear. !) to make it searchable for others with the same problem "Where's my app.config" and to make it "unsearchable" for those looking for the answer to the question linked above

Comment: thanks, that was my problem, I changed the title as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own app.config file to your project. Right click the project and add new items. Then add the lines that was given in the other link.