# Complete event wont fire when called in mvc async controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bluetooth

I using a wrapper to the [WCL](http://www.btframework.com/) BT library. Since the app is in .NET 4 and the license we have to the wrapper is in .NET 2, this is a sloppy workaround.

Using this wrapper with a .NET 4 WPF application works fine as long as the `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy` is on. More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode). It takes around 22 seconds firing the OnDiscoveryComplete event.

But when using the same wrapper with an ASP NET MVC 3 application, the OnDiscoveryComplete  event on the library is never fired. Anyone knows why?

The wrapper is called on buttonClickedEvent on the WPF app and on a SearchAsync action on an AsyncController on the MVC app.

The relevant code is here:

Calling the wrapper:

```
var wrapper = new Wrapper();
wrapper.Search();
```

Wrapper:

```
public Wrapper() {
    _wclApi = new wclAPI();
    _wclApi.Load();
     _btDiscovery = new wclBluetoothDiscovery();
    _btDiscovery.OnDiscoveryStarted += BtDiscoveryOnDiscoveryStarted;
    _btDiscovery.OnDiscoveryComplete += BtDiscoveryOnDiscoveryComplete;
}

public void Search() {
    var radios = new wclBluetoothRadios();
    var ret = _btDiscovery.EnumRadios(radios);

    if (ret == 0) {
        wclBluetoothRadio radio = radios[0];
        _btDiscovery.Discovery(radio, 0x15);
    }
}

private void BtDiscoveryOnDiscoveryComplete(object sender, wclBluetoothDiscoveryCompleteEventArgs e) {
    // handle devices found
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably an exception that the `wclBluetoothDiscovery` is encountering but not properly exposing to you.  It's a common bug in async APIs to not inform callers when bad things happen... the proper API design would be to raise the *Complete event but then raise the exception to you when you query the completed event args.

Comment: The line _btDiscovery.Discovery(radio, 0x15); is returning 0. So it's not on the Discovery method. Maybe on the callback.

Comment: @Daniel, if the Discovery method is async (it just kicks off a background process to do the actual work and then returns immediately) then the hidden exception would be in that background process and occurs after you get the 0 return value

Comment: @Daniel, also why the heck do you have a web app doing bluetooth discovery?

Comment: It's a backoffice App to work on a LAN environment so the devices he's searching will in fact be there.

Comment: Well, I guess it's really a bug with the WCL library