# conflict versions of libraries

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have project in VS2010 based of .net 4.0

And I try to include external dll, based of .net 3.5.

I get warning conflict versions of libraries and external dll does not load...

Source code of external dll does not have.

What I can do?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: are you using .net 4 or .net 4 client profile for your target framework?

Comment: I think you hit submit too early .. please edit to make it relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need featues of .net 4.0 in your project? (you could set the .net framework to 3.5 in the Project propertys.)

Otherwise you could make a wrapping project.
: Add a new .net 3.5 c# Project to your solution and add the reference to your 3.5 dll. Then reference the wrapper project from your initial project and you should be able to use the classes from the dll.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your app.config (in the configuration tag):

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

This should enable you to use mixed mode assemblies that are built for CLR 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Not clear whether this is your problem, but here is a solution to a similar issue:
[What 'additional configuration' is necessary to reference a .NET 2.0 mixed mode assembly in a .NET 4.0 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode)