# How can I receive SQL Server profiler events?

Tags: c#, sql-server, events, profiling, trace

I was tried like so:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace;

namespace SqlProfiller
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TraceServer reader = new TraceServer();
        SqlConnectionInfo connInfo = new SqlConnectionInfo();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connInfo.ServerName = @".\SQLR2";
            connInfo.DatabaseName = "DB";
            connInfo.UserName = "sa";
            connInfo.Password = "123";

            reader.InitializeAsReader(connInfo, @"Standard.tdf");


            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SPID  : " + reader["SPID"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Login : " + reader["SessionLoginName"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Object: " + reader["ObjectName"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Text  : " + reader["TextData"]);
                Console.WriteLine();

                textBox1.Text += "Event : " + reader["EventClass"] + Environment.NewLine;
                textBox1.Text += "SPID  : " + reader["SPID"] + Environment.NewLine;
                textBox1.Text += "Login : " + reader["SessionLoginName"] + Environment.NewLine;
                textBox1.Text += "Object: " + reader["ObjectName"] + Environment.NewLine;
                textBox1.Text += "Text  : " + reader["TextData"] + Environment.NewLine;
                textBox1.Text += "----------------------------------------------------------";
                textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> *Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.SqlTraceException: Failed to
>   initialize object as reader. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Mixed
>   mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and
>   cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration
>   information.*

**Failed to initialize object as reader.**

What does this mean?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`What does this mean?`

`System.IO.FileLoadException: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.`

It means that your process in running as a .NET 4 process and the assembly you are loading is .NET 2 compiled (`Microsoft.SqlServer.Management`).

Either recompile your application to use .NET 2 or [add a hint for .NET 4 in config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode) to allow .NET 2 assemblies.

Answer (score 3):

If running your code (build in VS 2013 using .NETFramework v 4.5 against Microsoft SQL server 2008, you are getting the following error:

Failed to initialize object as reader.
Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additiona
l configuration information.

You can fix it by changing your App.config in VS project, from default:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

to this one (small addition)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup  useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Plus, when I added Assembly using Solution -> add Assembly -> Browse, I used "100" folder, instead of "110" in the path below:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfoExtended.dll
```

But, may be it will be working with 110 as well.

I hope, this solution will help.