# how to solve FileLoadException: Mixed mode assembly in linqPad

Tags: c#, exception, linqpad

i'm new user for linqpad and when i try use it for explorer MS UCMA sdk

```
ProvisionedApplicationPlatformSettings paps = new ProvisionedApplicationPlatformSettings("string","string");
CollaborationPlatform platform = new CollaborationPlatform(paps);
platform.Dump();
```

give me an Exception

```
FileLoadException: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information
```

Comment: what's the question? because I bet you understand the exception just as I do. linked mixed mode assembly is .net2 while your application runs .net4, which does not work. did you try building your app in .net2? (or can you get your library in .net4?)

Comment: how can i solve this in linqpad ,, it is not an application just two line of code in linqpad

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode

Comment: thanks @EricDahlvang i know that but i ask how i can do this configuration in linqpad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Get the beta LinqPad .NET 4.0  and it work without exception

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the standalone executable version of LINQPad, make sure that the supplied configuration file is present (LINQPad.exe.config).