# I got an error when working with SQLite in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I get an error

> *Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.*

What shall I do?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an app.Config file and set useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy to true.

This is required to use mixed mode CLR 2 assemblies in a .NET 4 application.