# Import older assembly into .NET 4.0 project

Tags: vb.net, dll, .net-4.0

So, I'm going along testing my VB.net 2010 app, when the IDE goes into debugging mode for a `FileLoadException`.  The debugger says `Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.`  When I add the code in the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode), I get an unhandled `ConfigurationErrorException: Configuration system failed to initialize` in the file `Settings.Designer.vb` at the code:

```
Public Property needsSetup() As Boolean
        Get
            Return CType(Me("needsSetup"),Boolean) ''It gives the error here.''
        End Get
        Set
            Me("needsSetup") = value
        End Set
End Property
```

Here is the code I am trying to get working:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dblist() As Array = sqlQuery()
End Sub

Function sqlQuery()
    Dim dbConnection As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("database.sqlite")
    dbConnection.Open()
    Dim readCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand()
    readCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM thetablez"
    Dim sqlReader As SQLiteDataReader
    sqlReader = readCommand.ExecuteReader()
    Dim list(1) As String
    Dim cntr As Integer = 1
    While (sqlReader.Read())
        list(cntr) = sqlReader("identifier")
        ReDim Preserve list(list.Length + 1)
        cntr += 1
    End While
    dbConnection.Close()
    Return list
End Function
```

I really need this library to work, otherwise I'm copying 32mb of stuff into my application code!  Please help, and if you have the solution, your username will be in the credits (ooh, an incentive).  Thanks!

Comment: a quick google search reveals the answer.  Also, a quick SO search.  Do your homework before you ask us to.

Comment: It's always a great idea to Google the exact error message you're getting (at least the first few words of it) before you start posting questions anywhere. Odds are you're not the first person to ever see that error.

Comment: I now have a different error, after I make the changes suggested.