# Library .NET version exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mixed-mode

Im trying do my first steps in Winforms development with C# and .NET framework.
I want to make a little users CRUD application. I have the SQLite db populated with test data.

So, i create a blank project solution, and added a "Class library" project called "DataBundle".

In the DataBundle, have the entity class for the database, mapped with Entity Framework.

Also, i created a console application for test my DataBundle. The app build correctlly, but when try run querys the application throw an exception.

This is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Testeando el DataBudnle ...");
mainContext _dao = new mainContext();

Zone city = new Zone
{
  name = "Ensenada"
};

Console.WriteLine("Existen {0} ciudades registradas ...", _dao.Zones.Count());
Console.ReadLine();
```

And the exception message is:

> The mixed-mode assembly is compiled with 'v2.0.50727' version of the
>   runtime and can not be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional
>   configuration information.

Im using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, Windows 7 Professional with .NET 4 Framework installed.

Any ideas ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steve suggested there, add this in the console application App.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```