# Mixed mode assembly exception

Tags: c#

Can any one explain this exception?

Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPouJ.png

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a CLR 2.0 mixed mode assembly, you need to modify your App.Config file to include:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

taken from: [What 'additional configuration' is necessary to reference a .NET 2.0 mixed mode assembly in a .NET 4.0 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode)