# .Net 4.6 EXE Calling .Net 2.0 Assembly fails with PermissionSet Exception

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

Recently was adding NLog into a .Net exe. Took the opportunity to recompile to .Net 4.6 from .Net 2.0.  The exe calls a vendor library which uses .net 2.0. Certain method of the vendor library throws a Request Failed that indicates a securityPermission exception when the vendor library tries to call OpenMutex. Disassembling the vendor lib shows the offending code:

```
  [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.PermitOnly)]
    static private void InitMutex(string path)
    {
        string name = string.Format("AMutexName");
        if (dataMutex != null)
        {
            //this.FinalizeMutex();
        }
        bool flag;
        dataMutex = new OpenMutex(false, Common.GlobalMutexName(name), out flag);
```

The issue appears to be with the attribute action of PermitOnly. I added the code directly into the 4.6 exe for easier testing and found if I change securityaction to almost any other value the OpenMutex calls succeeds. 
My question is if there is a way to grant permissions to my exe so the vendor code will succeed? The original EXE compiled under 2.0 works.

Comment: You "might" be out of luck. As security/permission model has changed from  WF2

Comment: There's a way to set the security model to legacy but I have zero experience with it so I don't know if it would help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409253.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alex. I tried it and it does not work. If I compile back to a .net version prior to 4 the calls work. I know, as TS mentioned above the security model related to CAS changed starting with .net 4.0. Just havent found the way to ring fence the old code so its usable by new.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode?rq=1) help?